# Wifi doesn’t work after switching providers

Tags: wireless

I change internet provider to Bell and after it, all computers and phones are run no problem, except dell laptop Latitude E6440 with OS Ubuntu 21.04.

1. firefox cannot open amy websites
2. my wifi signal symbol on top of the bar shows question mark “?” On top of the rainbow wifi signal.

Wireless adaptor is Centrino Advance -N 6235 if it useful

---

NDLcideCH; i went into router setting. Both mac and ip address correct. Other devices have own/different ip addresses. I switched from dynamic to reserved as you suggested. See photo. Still do not have wifi. Or how do i do what you have suggested?[image]

Comment: Did you get new network equipment?

Comment: The "?" symbol on the Wifi icon usually means DNS problems. Did you get a new WiFi router from Bell? What are the "default Route" and "DNS Settings" in your Dell laptop's Network Manager? What are these settings in your new router? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1365408/edit) and add all these information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try this

Go to your Ubuntu Dell computer's Settings > WiFi as shown below:

[image]

The top entry with a check mark should be your new WiFi access point. Click on the "Gears" button next to it to get to the WiFi settings.

Then verify the Details tab as shown above. The **IPv4 address** should be what you have set in the router as reserved and as shown in the picture in the question.

The **Default Route** and the **DNS** should be the IP address of the router. I assume it is 192.168.2.1. If this is not the IP address of the new router, then go to the next step.

Click on the **IPv4** tab circled in the picture above. You should see something like this:

[image]

Make sure:

- **IPv4 Method** is set to **Automatic (DHCP** and
- **DNS** is set to **Automatic**.

If this does not solve the problem, update your question with the Default Route to the new router and other settings you currently have.

Hope this helps